# Attempting to catch duplicate attributes in JSON when unmarshalling in Go

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

Im trying to accomplish the following in my Go application :

I want to receive a JSON string, and make sure the same attribute is not declared at the same level. For instance, something like this :

```
{
   "name" : "Matias",
   "Age"  : 16,
   "Age"  : 31
}
```

Would need to throw an error that I already declare *Age* before. The thing is, below you can see what I have reached so far, when I get the string unmarshalled I lost the repeated attributes. So in my *map[string]interface{}* which I am iterating over, there is no repeated fields, but there is in the original string which is coming loaded from a file.

Has anyone any idea of how I can accomplish this?

```
func catchDuplicates(unm_spec *interface{}) []models.Result {
    m := (*unm_spec).(map[string]interface{})
    already_seen := make(map[string]bool)

    for k, v := range m {
        if already_seen[k] == false {
            fmt.Println("It seems its the first time I see this : ", k , " ", already_seen[k] )
            already_seen[k] = true
        }else {
            fmt.Println("I got a duplicate here ", k , " ", already_seen[k] )
            results = append(results, models.Result{ 
                false,
                k,
                true,
                "This attribute was already declared",
                "no_dup error",
            })
        }
        switch vv := v.(type) {
        case string:
            //fmt.Println(k, "is string", vv)
        case float64:
            fmt.Println(k, "is float64", vv)
        case []interface{}:
            //fmt.Println(k, "is an array:")
        default:
            //fmt.Println(k, "is of a type I don't know how to handle")
        }
    }
    return results
}
```

Comment: You probably have to do this the hard way by decoding one token at a time: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Token (take a look at the example).

Comment: Thanks everyone. the duplicated answer helped me to accomplish what I was looking for.